# Iterating one the lists, when it is not known which one should be on the outer loop

Tags: collections, java-8

I have 2 lists that are built at runtime:

`List<ReportEntity> existingEntities = //get somehow`

`List<Device> devices = //get somehow`

ReportEntity.java

```
...
    private String deviceId;
...
```

Device.java

```
...
    private String id;
...
```

The lists have objects of different types!

The sizes of these lists will not be known until runtime. The requirement is to process the common elements in the list differently than the remaining. Since the sizes are not known before-hand, I can't put any one list in the outer `for-loop`.

Please can some light be shed around how to handle this?

Example loop structure when `existingEntities.size() > devices.size()`:

```
for (ReportEntity exitingEntity : existingEntities) {
  for (Device device : devices) {
      if (existingEntity.getDeviceId().equals(device.getId())) {
          // do something; 
      }
  }
}

// HOW DO WE NO KNOW WHAT DEVICES WERE NOT PROCESSED
```

Comment: yes you can, you can simply compare their sizes. But also, you can consider using sets and the intersection of them

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was so hung up on ```List``` that couldn't think that I can easily cover to ```Set``` especially when we know that either list will not have duplicates. Thanks

Comment: I asked the question in a very simplified way in the beginning. I have now updated the question. Can you please suggest how to handle this?

Comment: Why you need to decide one of the list for outer for-loop ? Question is not clear.